# I want to copy filenames in dynamic folder on right-klick to clipboard but zip

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, registry

I want to copy filenames on right-clicking the containing folder to clipboard, but if there are `zip`, `iso`, `rar`, or `7z` files I need a list of the content from them too.

I tried in `batch/cmd` but it won't work and now I am testing with C#. But I don't know how to simulate an explorer `contextmenue-event` to send the parameters to C#-App.

On both ways I start with a regedit entry in:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Liste\command\` REG_SZ with attribute C:\liste.bat "%1%"`
```

liste.bat:

```
set var=%1\
set listtmp
del c:\ESC\* /q /f
dir c:\ESC\
copy %var% c:\ESC\
cd c:\ESC\
dir  /s /b >%listtmp%
if exist c:\ESC\*.zip
(7z l *.zip >>%listtmp%)
if exist c:\ESC\*.7z
(7z l *.7z >>%listtmp%)
echo listtmp|clip
```

C# offers the benefit of list handling in variables and enums for checking archives, but I don't understand how to use the parameter from a drop-menu to start my C#-app, so the batch is more handy, with C#-exes more people have doubt because adware... paranoid colleague ;)

I think there is a way, without copping the files and without that amount of variables. Oh and sorry when I not mentioned a vary necessary thing, this is my first post.

Comment: _"I tried in batch/cmd but it won't work..."_. Where? How? With which error? If that's your batch then I'd first check `IF` syntax (`(7z ...)` must begin on the same line of `IF`). I didn't even read the rest

Comment: Sorry on WinXP I'm scripting with an editor in batch-file. There are no errors at all, but not the goal I want to reach. I put the brackets on the same line as     IF     but there nothing changed. Yesterday I started with Powershell, do I think it have no problems with multi-lined-text in variable, but... is it working to use arrays in batch-file?

Comment: Arrays in batch file (non ps)? Not without dirty half-working tricks. Anyway what I mean is: DESCRIBE,  WRITE, EXPLAIN what it does and what it doesn't. "it doesn't work" is far from enough to understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

Next `C:\bat\dirToClp.bat` file could help with your *I want to copy filenames on right-clicking the containing folder to clipboard*:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
@SETLOCAL enableextensions
set "listtmp=%tmp%\list.tmp"
pushd "%~1"
dir /S /B /A-D>"%listtmp%"
if exist *.zip 7z l *.zip>>"%listtmp%"
if exist *.7z 7z l *.7z>>"%listtmp%"
type "%listtmp%"|clip
del "%listtmp%"
popd
echo Your clipboard now holds result of:
echo dir %CD%
pause 
@ENDLOCAL
@goto :eof
```

Here `echo` and `pause` for when using `clip` in a batch script you should warn the user that their clipboard is about to be overwritten. Eventually `/A-D` switch could be removed from `dir /S /B /A-D` if desired (causes folder names *not* implicated in list).

Please pay your attention to `7z` calls since I can't verify and confirm rightness of.

The value `c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /C c:\bat\dirToClp "%1"` exported from registry as follows (but could be under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder` registry key instead of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory`):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\DirToClipboard]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\DirToClipboard\command]
@="c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /D /C c:\\bat\\dirToClp \"%1\""


;
```

Here is not pure `C:\bat\dirToClp.bat` call but via `cmd.exe /D /C` because, for workaday and security reasons, I use "Open with PSPad" default action for `.bat`, `.cmd`, `.vbs` etc.

Also the batch saved in that `C:\bat` folder for I avoid  placing files to disk root (and to `%userprofile%` root and to *desktop* as well) as a matter of general principle.